# Simple way to validate a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of javascript objects that are dynamic, I want to just want to verify the objects are "valid"

I want to do it as fast and efficiently a possible, so this nested if loop system feels inefficent

```
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty("key")){
                if(obj.hasOwnProperty("value")){
                  if(obj.hasOwnProperty("message")){
                    //we only want active objects!
                    if(obj.Active){
                      Array.push(obj);
                    }
                  } 
                }
              }
```

Comment: Use a library that will validate against [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/).

Comment: It's correct.. wats the issue?

Comment: No need to go with library ..I think it's overhead

Comment: @NegiRox It sounds like he wants to validate objects against a schema (make sure this property is on the object, make sure that property only has values of Boolean type, etc).

Comment: Building on @zero298's comment: https://github.com/hapijs/joi

Comment: "nested if loop". `if` is not a loop. Loops are `for` and `while`.

Answer (score 4):

Well you could add a list of required properties in an array and iterate over that to test that [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) property exists

So

```js
let validObj = ['key', 'value', 'message'];
let validate = (obj,props) => props.every(prop => obj.hasOwnProperty(prop));

// now you can use
if (validate(obj, validObj) && obj.Active) ArrayVar.push(obj);
```

Comment: the definetly looks much cleaner!